# Single make file for multiple main.cpp files

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a project in which multiple situations need to be calculated, all using the same headers and dependencies. The directory hierarchy is as such.

```
/src/Chapter_4/Exercise_4.7.cpp
/src/Chapter_4/Exercise_4.9.cpp
/src/Chapter_4/Exercise_4.12.cpp (etc...)
/src/Chapter_4/Makefile

/src/header1.h
/src/header2.h (etc...)
```

I want to have the single Makefile that lets me run the command "make Exercise_4.(whatever)" and compiles that particular Exercise file. I really don't want to edit the Makefile every time I want to compile a different Exercise.

Keep in mind that I am very, very new to using make files.

Comment: Your makefile can have as many targets as is needed, so just create a target for each Exercise_4.(whatever). If you instead want a more elegant solution, you'll need to research make in more depth rather than posting here - but once you've researched enough to make an honest attempt, if it doesn't work feel free to post a question including what you've tried and how it fails to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work I think

```
%: %.cpp
    g++ $< -I../ -o $@
```

The rule name is same as the cpp file. So if you want to compile Excercise_4.cpp just use `make Excercise_4`. `$<` refers to your input arguments, `$@` to the target name.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your dependencies (or lack thereof), you don't even need to write a Makefile at all. Simply doing:

```
$ cd /src/Chapter_4
$ make Exercice_4.x
```

... with `x` matching the one of the file you want to compile is enough because Make has a lot of implicit rules that are built-in, and it has one to compile an executable from a source file of the same name.

You can see it by doing:

```
$ make -p | grep -C2 "%.cpp"
```

... output is:

```
%: %.cpp
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(LINK.cpp) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Using similar commands, we see that `$(LINK.cpp)` expands to `$(LINK.cc)` which expands to `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)`.

So when you call `make Exercice_4.19`, it will execute something like:

```
g++     Exercice_4.19.cpp   -o Exercice_4.19
```

If you want to, let's say, add flags for warning or use a certain standard version, you can simply add the flag on the fly:

```
$ make Exercice_4.19 CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -Wall"
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall    Exercice_4.19.cpp   -o Exercice_4.19
```

Or write it in your Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall
```

And then call it like before:

```
$ make Exercice_4.19
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall    Exercice_4.19.cpp   -o Exercice_4.19
```

You don't need to bother with writing rules at all for such a simple task.